# Reflecting ray on triangle in 3D space

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d

I am working in a 3D space. I have a ray, or more specifically the start and transmission vector of a ray in 3D space. I also have a triangle, which I know for a fact is hit by the ray. By triangle I of course mean I have three 3D points. I can also calculate a normal vector from this triangle easily.

Now I need to get a new ray, which would be the reflection after that specific hit.

I also don't know exacltly where on the triangle the point of contact is, but it obviously has to be taken into account to get the reflected ray. That point would be the start of that new ray.

This is trivial to do in 2D, but I can't figure out how to do it in 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

By $\,\, \times \,\, $ I denote cross-product and by $(\,\, \cdot \,\, )$  I denote dot product. The length of a vector is $|\vec{u}| = \sqrt{(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u})}$.

Look at the picture. $S$ is the source of the light ray and the direction of the ray is denoted by $\vec{v}$. The three points are $A, \, B, \, C$. Say $O$ is the origin of your coordinate system. Now, the unit normal vector to the plane determined by points $A, \, B, \, C$ can be calculated for example as 
$$\vec{n} = \frac{\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}}{\big|\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}\big|}$$ Vector $\vec{OK}$ in the right side of the picture is the orthogonal projection of vector $\vec{v} = \vec{OM}$ onto $\vec{n}$ and is thus defined as
$$\vec{OK} = (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{n})\, \vec{n}$$ so twice the vector $\vec{OK}$ is
$$\vec{OL} = 2 \,\vec{OK} = 2\, (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{n}) \, \vec{n}$$ Thus, the reflected vector is $$\vec{w} = \vec{LM} = \vec{OM} - \vec{OL} = \vec{v} -  2\, (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{n}) \, \vec{n}$$

Now the intersection point $R$ between the light ray and the plane $A, B, C$. The vector equation for the plane $A, B, C$ can be written as $$\vec{n} \cdot \big(\vec{OX} - \vec{OA}\big) = 0$$ where $X$ is any point on the plane and $\vec{OX}$ is its position (coordinate) vector, i.e. the vector pointing from the origin $O$ to the point $X$. The equation for the light ray is $$\vec{OX} = \vec{OS} + t \, \vec{v}$$ for any point $X$ on the light ray ($t\geq 0$ in order to have a ray). Thus the intersection point $R$ should satisfy both equations, i.e. 
\begin{align}
&\vec{n} \cdot \big(\vec{OR} - \vec{OA}\big) = 0\\
&\vec{OR} = \vec{OS} + t \, \vec{v}
\end{align} so substitute the second equation in the first and
\begin{align}
0 &= \vec{n} \cdot \big(\vec{OS} + t \, \vec{v} - \vec{OA}\big) = \vec{n} \cdot \big(\vec{OS}  - \vec{OA} + t \, \vec{v} \big) = \vec{n} \cdot \big(\vec{AS} + t \, \vec{v} \big) = \big(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{AS}\big) + t  \big(\vec{n} \cdot  \vec{v} \big)
\end{align} 
and when you solve for $t$ you get
$$t = \frac{- \big(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{AS}\big)}{\big(\vec{n} \cdot  \vec{v} \big)} = \frac{\big(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{SA}\big)}{\big(\vec{n} \cdot  \vec{v} \big)}$$ notice $\vec{SA} = - \vec{AS}$. Therefore, 
$$\vec{OR} = \vec{OS} +  \frac{\big(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{SA}\big)}{\big(\vec{n} \cdot  \vec{v} \big)} \, \vec{v}$$

Thus, the reflected ray is given by the following point $R$ and vector $\vec{w}$ 
\begin{align}
\vec{OR} &= \vec{OS} +  \frac{\big(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{SA}\big)}{\big(\vec{n} \cdot  \vec{v} \big)} \, \vec{v}\\
\vec{w} &=  \vec{v} -  2\, (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{n}) \, \vec{n}\\
\vec{n} &= \frac{\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}}{\big|\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}\big|}
\end{align}
You can permute the points $A, B, C$ any way you want, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the normal is $\vec{n}$, the incident beam is $\vec{v}$, and the scattered beam is $\vec{u}$. Assume that $|\vec{v}|=\vec{u}=\vec{n}=1$. The normal is the bisector between vectors $ \vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$. Then $\vec{v}-\vec{u}$ is along $\vec{n}$. The component of $\vec{v}$ along $\vec{n}$ is $(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n})\vec{n}$, so $\vec{u}=\vec{v}+2(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n})\vec{n}$

Comment: If I may ask, is vn in your scenario (how do you put the arrows over the letters?) the dot product? Same goes for all multiplication of vectors in your formulaes

Comment: Also, I can get the normal, but part of the question was also about how to get the specific point where the ray hits the triangle, to set the start of the new ray.

Comment: @KaitoKid If you have the normal and any point on the triangle, you can produce an equation for the plane of the triangle. The point at which the ray hits the triangle satisfies this equation.

Comment: "You can produce an equation" -> would you mind sharing how to do that exactly?

Comment: You also haven't mentioned if the default multiplication in your calculation is the cross product.

Comment: @KaitoKid I did not use cross product anywhere

Comment: If you want more detail, share exactly what are your given inputs, and I mean what is the format

Comment: I already did that. I have a ray, in the form of a start point and a transmission vector (both 3D). I also have three points that define a triangle which I know for a fact the ray intersects with, but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: @KaitoKid Look up “normal equation of a plane” or “point-normal form of a plane.”

Comment: @KaitoKid is the equation of your transmission vector given in parametric form? like $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ for $t>0$? If yes, then plug in those functions into the equation of the plane of the triangle, and you find $t$. Then you can find the intersection by plugging in that value in the above parametric form